# Reverse proxy for a NodeJS website

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, varnish

I look for a reverse proxy for my *NodeJS* website. I thought of *Varnish* or *nginx* or something else.

What would you suggest me and why (do not necessarily focus on *Varnish* vs *nginx*)?

Comment: If you're looking for product/software/tool recommendations, that isn't allowed here.

Comment: What is your purpose of using a reverse proxy? Caching, load balancing, security, SSL termination...?

Comment: @Manish Maheshwari good question! The main goal in a first time is to forward http requests on the port 80 to my nodejs app. Of course, I think of caching and load balancing in a second time and these aspects may be argued in your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`nginx` would probably be the best stand-alone solution, however, when I'm working with Node.js, I prefer to keep everything in Node.js so I don't have to worry about the (relatively simple) configuration. I personally use [`node-reverse-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-reverse-proxy), which allows me to just specify some simple routes in a simple application, and then route it back to the individual applications.

This is the `node-reverse-proxy` sample code:

```
var node_reverse_proxy = require('node-reverse-proxy');

var ip = '127.0.0.1';
var reverse_proxy = new node_reverse_proxy({
    'first_host.com' : ip + ':8082',
    'my.second_host.com' : ip + ':8081',
    'my.second_host.com/page/' : ip + ':8080',
    '' : ip + ':8080' // catch all other routes
});

reverse_proxy.start(80);
```

You might find that `nginx` better suits your needs, but personally, for a simple reverse proxy setup, I do prefer `node-reverse-proxy`.